# Group specific dependencies in CMake-generated solution?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I'm using CMake to generate the Visual Studio solution for my project, and inside it I'm using many third party libraries and when I generate the solution it looks like this:

[image]

I want to create a specific group for third party, just like cmake is creating one for "CMakePredefinedTargets"

How can I do that?

This is my main CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(VoidEngine)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -DEN_DEBUG")
ADD_DEFINITIONS(
    -std=c++17 # Or -std=c++0x
    # Other flags
)
include(C:/Users/user/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)
add_subdirectory(Game)
add_subdirectory(Engine)
add_subdirectory(Server)
add_subdirectory(HeadlessClient)
# ---------------- Third party modules -------------------
add_subdirectory(ThirdParty/SDL2)
add_subdirectory(ThirdParty/zlib)

# ---- Steam Game Networking sockets definitions ------
add_definitions(-DBUILD_STATIC_LIB=1)

add_subdirectory(ThirdParty/GameNetworkingSockets)

remove_definitions(-DBUILD_STATIC_LIB=1)
# ------------------------------------------------------

add_subdirectory(ThirdParty/bgfx-cmake)

target_link_libraries (Game Engine SDL2-static bgfx)
target_link_libraries (HeadlessClient Engine SDL2-static bgfx protobuf GameNetworkingSockets_s)
```

Comment: fixed by adding ```set(CMAKE_FOLDER "${CMAKE_FOLDER}/third_party")``` right before I add third party sub directories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FOLDER` property on a target tells generators to put that target in a folder. You can use the `CMAKE_FOLDER` to do this for all targets in a directory.